# Jasmine - wait for fadeOut() to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have a simple function which fades in an element:

**CODE**

```
checkLengthSelect: function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){ // if not empty
        $('.c--error').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#button').fadeIn();
        })
    } else { // if empty hide button and show error message
        $('#button').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('.c--error').html('foo').fadeIn(); // <-- I want to test this on fadeOut callback
        })
    }
},
```

I'm trying to write a test for it like this:

**TEST**

```
it("it should have a value or hide continue button", function(){

    // check cover length on select
    $(document).on('change', '#select', function(){ qqw.validate.checkLengthSelect.call(this) } );

    // force a change event to fire with empty value.
    $('#select').val('').change();

    setTimeout(function(){
        expect($('.c--error').html()).toEqual('foo');   
        done(); // <-- test if done
    }, 800);

});
```

**ERROR**

This shows in console

`'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out`

**QUESTION**

How can I test that an event happens when the `fadeOut` completes?

I'm using Jasmine v2+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test a function which has a setTimeout with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Jasmine 1.3

You can use [`waitsFor`](https://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-32) to wait for the condition or fail after a timeout:

```
waitsFor(function() {
  return $('.c--error').html() == 'foo';
}, "Error was never set to 'foo'", 800);
```

### Jasmine 2.0

For Jasmine 2.0, you can simulate the same behavior:

```
describe("stackoverflow test", function() {
    var originalTimeout;
    beforeEach(function() {
      originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });

    it("it should have a value or hide continue button", function(done) {

        // check cover length on select
        $(document).on('change', '#select', function(){ checkLengthSelect.call(this) } );

        // force a change event to fire with empty value.
        $('#select').val('').change();

        var POLL_TIME = 10;
        var endTime = new Date().getTime() + 5000;

        var checkCondition = function() {
            if (new Date().getTime() <= endTime && $('.c--error').html() != 'foo') {
                setTimeout(checkCondition, POLL_TIME);
            } else {
                expect($('.c--error').html()).toEqual('foo');  
                done();
            }
        };
        checkCondition();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
});
```

You need to [increase the async timeout](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-43) to keep the test from failing.  Adjust `POLL_TIME` or the amount added to the current date to change that behavior.  I should also note that your current code will not hit the correct branch of `checkLengthSelect` so the test will fail, I flipped the condition on that branch in my testing to make sure the Jasmine part of this works as expected.

Comment: `waitsFor` is not in Jasmine any more since I believe v2.0

Comment: Updated the answer with a Jasmine 2.0 solution

Comment: Thanks Jake, I figured this out too with the same solution but will accept answer for the polling

Answer (score 1):

use

```
jasmine.clock().tick(801);
```

to advance the timer.

http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html