# How to test spy in setTimeout using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have code like this:

```
it('should call json-rpc', function() {
    var spy = spyOn(object, 'echo');
    if (spy.andCallThrough) {
        spy.andCallThrough();
    } else {
        spy.and.callThrough();
    }
    enter(term, 'echo foo bar');
    setTimeout(function() {
        // here I've got error Expected a spy, but got Function.
        expect(object.echo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', 'bar');
        term.destroy().remove();
    }, 200);
});
```

and I've got error that object.echo is not a spy but function, how can I check if function was called in setTimeout?

**EDIT**: I've tried use this:

```
if (jasmine.Clock) {
    jasmine.Clock.useMock();
} else {
    jasmine.clock().install();
}
```

and

```
if (jasmine.Clock) {
    jasmine.Clock.tick(200);
} else {
    jasmine.clock().tick(200);
}
expect(object.echo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', 'bar');
```

but this also don't work. I've got error

```
Expected spy echo to have been called with [ 'foo', 'bar' ] but it was never called.
```

Comment: I think the expectation should just be on your local variable for the spy, which you are calling spy so: `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @hightempo yes it work, you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expectations should be on the local JavaScript local variable instance for the spy.  So in your case you should use:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith
```

Comment: `toHaveBeenCalledWith`..should not you be calling the matcher?

Comment: @alecxe - yes, I was just posting part of the code -- the part that @jcubic would have to change to get it to work.  The full line would be `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', 'bar');`

Comment: A couple suggestions, consider using $timeout and calling flush on it as opossed to setTimeout.  Also you can add an afterEach() function to do things like tearing down:  term.destroy().remove();

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to also tell jasmine the test is done after the `setTimeout`. E.g. for jasmine 2.0 something like this (see link for jasmine 1.3 and more)

> You can use done, the test callback:
>
> ```
> it('should call json-rpc', function(done) {
>     var spy = spyOn(object, 'echo');
>     if (spy.andCallThrough) {
>         spy.andCallThrough();
>     } else {
>         spy.and.callThrough();
>     }
>     enter(term, 'echo foo bar');
>     setTimeout(function() {
>         // here I've got error Expected a spy, but got Function.
>         expect(object.echo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', 'bar');
>         term.destroy().remove();
>         done();
>     }, 200);
> });
> ```

taken here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10955536/5272567