# How to test requestAnimationFrame with jasmine(2.4) testing?

Tags: jasmine, requestanimationframe

I am new in jasmine testing and I have searched the test case example for requestAnimationFrame in jasmine [document](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html), but I couldn't find it.

I found this [plugin](https://gist.github.com/ischenkodv/43934774f4509fcb5791) to create mock requestAnimationFrame, but I need to use jasmine inbuilt option to test requestAnimationFrame.

Is there any option to test the requestAnimationFrame with jasmine using inbuilt functionalities?

Comment: What is it about requestAnimationFrame that you would like to test? By this I mean, if you were to write this test – what would you write as the labels for the `describe` and `it` blocks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a function which has a setTimeout with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine)

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout()` and `done()`:

```
it("Spec with requestAnimationFrame", (done) => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        // Do something testable here
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Verify testable values here

        done();
    }, 200);
});
```