# Test a function that contains a setTimeout()

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, settimeout, karma-jasmine

I have a close function in my component that contains a `setTimeout()` in order to give time for the animation to complete.

```
public close() {
    this.animate = "inactive"
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.show = false
    }, 250)
}
```

`this.show` is bound to an `ngIf`.

`this.animate` is bound to an animation.

I have a test that needs to test this function

```
it("tests the exit button click", () => {
  comp.close()
  fixture.detectChanges()
  //verifies the element is no longer in the DOM
  const popUpWindow = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#popup-window"))
  expect(popUpWindow).toEqual(null)
})
```

How do you properly test this function when there is a `setTimeout()`?

I was using `jasmine.clock().tick(251)` but the window would never disappear. any thoughts on this as well?

Comment: Have you tried using `done`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How exactly

Comment: Then I'd recommend you start your research there; it's for testing asynchronous processes.

Comment: Not what you originally asked, but instead of using a timeout, you can use the `done` event that Angular fires.  In your template, you can use `<my-tag [@myAnimation]="animate" (@myAnimation.done)="show=false">` -- the `.done` event code will run immediately after your animation completes.

Comment: **See also** [test setTimeout with Jasmine (but witout Angular)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You could do one of two things:

1: Actually wait in the test 250+1 ms in a `setTimeout()`, then check if the element actually disappeared.

2: use `fakeAsync()` and `tick()` to simulate time in the test - a `tick()` will resolve the setTimeout in the original `close()`, and the check could happen right after in a `fixture.whenStable().then(...)`.

For example:

```
it("tests the exit button click", fakeAsync(() => {
  comp.close()
  tick(500)
  fixture.detectChanges()

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    const popUpWindow = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#popup-window"))
    expect(popUpWindow).toBe(null)
  })
}))
```

I suggest using the 2nd one, as it is much more faster than actually waiting for the original method. If you still use the 1st, try lowering the timeout time before the test to make the it run faster.

SEVICES

For services you do not need to call `detectChanges` after `tick` and do not need to wrap the expect statements within `whenStable`. you can do your logic right after `tick`.

```js
  it('should reresh token after interval', fakeAsync(() => {
    // given
    const service: any = TestBed.get(CognitoService);
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'refreshToken').and.callThrough();
    ....
    // when
    service.scheduleTokenRefresh();
    tick(TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL);
    // then
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Comment: Thank you. The second one worked, but was a little more complex then simply using tick(). I had to wrap the `expects` within a `fixture.whenStable().then( ... //expects )`. If you allow me to update your answer with this additional info I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: To add to that, you may need an additional `fixture.detectChanges()` *before* the `tick`. Then you may not need `fixture.whenStable()` at all (afaik fakeAsync was designed precisely to avoid such async calls).

Comment: incase it helps anyone else, the function that calls the setTimeout needs to be called within the fakeAsync method (can't be called in the beforeEach). Seems obvious but it got me!

Comment: try    jasmine.clock().tick(10);

Comment: ATTENTION: adding ````fixture.whenStable()```` is not only unneccessary (as mentioned by @dinvlad) but may also lead to tests passing although they are not correct. I tried this approach and my tests passed no matter what I expected. ````fixture.whenStable()```` should be deleted from the code block. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971537/what-is-the-difference-between-fakeasync-and-async-in-angular-testing

Answer (score 30):

In my component the method is:

```
hideToast() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.showToast = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Test for that (explanation in comments):

```
it('should hide toast', () => {
  component.showToast = true; // This value should change after timeout
  jasmine.clock().install();  // First install the clock
  component.hideToast();      // Call the component method that turns the showToast value as false
  jasmine.clock().tick(5000); // waits till 5000 milliseconds
  expect(component.showToast).toBeFalsy();  // Then executes this
  jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // uninstall clock when done
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 7):

Just tried this in my project and works:

```
jasmine.clock().tick(10);
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a method that is eerily similar to the OP's setup so thought I would add my test which I think is a lot simpler.

** Method **

```
public close() {
    this.animate = "inactive"
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.show = false
    }, 250)
}
```

** Jasmine Test **

```
it('should set show to "false" after 250ms when close is fired', (done) => {
      component.close();
      setTimeout(() => {
        expect(component.close).toBeFalse();
        done();
      }, 251);
    });
```

Note the use of 'done' to let jasmine know the test is finished and also adding 1 ms to the setTimeout to fire after my method's setTimeout.

Comment: Thats the clean way!

Comment: Does not work for me (Angular 16 with jasmine/karma), as it interfers with running more than this one test. Any other test may fail if this test fails, leading to the very strange case of the test title being "login" for example but actually failing somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

this solution mentioned by @Kailas works for me:

```
hideToast() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.showToast = false;
    }, 5000);
  }

it('should hide toast', () => {
  component.showToast = true; // This value should change after timeout
  jasmine.clock().install();  // First install the clock
  component.hideToast();      // Call the component method that turns the showToast value as false
  jasmine.clock().tick(5000); // waits till 5000 milliseconds
  expect(component.showToast).toBeFalsy();  // Then executes this
  jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // uninstall clock when done
});
```

but sometimes you will receive this error:

> Error: **Jasmine Clock was unable to install over custom global timer functions. Is the clock already installed?**

to resolve this issue you need to uninstall the clock first:

```
it('should hide toast', () => {
  jasmine.clock().uninstall()
  component.showToast = true; 
  jasmine.clock().install();  
  component.hideToast();      
  jasmine.clock().tick(5000); 
  expect(component.showToast).toBeFalsy();  
  jasmine.clock().uninstall(); 
});
```