# How to test code setup with babel configuration(For Library) using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, babeljs, karma-jasmine

Good day to all,

I am struggling from quite a few days and raised few questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313821/why-test-case-in-jasmine-are-failing-when-comparing-two-maps) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804740/jasmine-test-case-are-failing-when-testing-settimeout-inside-function) and I have narrowed them down to this question.

I have below babel configuration:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                "modules": false,
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", //target environment are not supported
             {
                 "corejs": 3,
                 "helpers": true,
                 "regenerator": true
             }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I also have a setup for jasmine with webpack and I am trying to test some of the module’s I have written.  But the problem is inside Jasmine they have set custom definition of [setTimeout](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/cd1131354bea551ef11478e313fe66fb11721cf4/src/core/Clock.js#L156) but the configuration of babel that I am using has included polyfills that will not pollute global environment and That’s why I am not able to use some of the feature’s provided by Jasmine and every time I have to pass my jasmine test I had to use window.Map([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313821/why-test-case-in-jasmine-are-failing-when-comparing-two-maps)) or window.setTimeout([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804740/jasmine-test-case-are-failing-when-testing-settimeout-inside-function))

I have raised to jasmine team [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1878#issuecomment-772675097) and someone gave me a helpful [response](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1878#issuecomment-772675097).

I am wondering if there is any way in babel that could help me to test my modules.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of struggle with multiple issue's raised, all drill down to this answer. (Will try to add all my r&d here)

Firstly, I am using below babel configuration as I am authoring library. Used Suggested configuration from *[Here](https://www.jmarkoski.com/understanding-babel-preset-env-and-transform-runtime)*

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                "modules": false,
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", //target environment are not supported
             {
                 "corejs": 3,
                 "helpers": true,
                 "regenerator": true
             }
        ]
    ]
}
```

At the same time I wanted to test my modules using [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) + [webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-webpack). But the problem is inside Jasmine they have set custom definition of [setTimeout](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/cd1131354bea551ef11478e313fe66fb11721cf4/src/core/Clock.js#L156) as well as multiple Matcher's utility for testing [Maps](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/1320b0614f0ad47981caab948b6a2cfd015e257b/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L4807) and the configuration of babel that I am using has included polyfills that will not pollute global environment. Because of this I was not able to use multiple feature's of jasmine like [Clock](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/Clock), Maps Equality using equals [Matchers](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/MatchersUtil.html). Actually babel was preventing Jasmine implementation making test script to fail.  Detail [Read Here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1878#issuecomment-772675097)

I reached out to Babel team with this problem, thinking if babel has some configuration that will resolve my problem to unit-test module's on local at the same time it does not affect my production bundle.

They suggested that this cannot be achieved with @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
with corejs option.

Steps to do:

- Remove the `corejs: 3` option from @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
- Install the new `babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3`, which is like transform-runtime's + corejs option but more powerful. [Documentation](https://github.com/babel/babel-polyfills/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3)
- Configure your babel like below:

```
["polyfill-corejs3", {
  method: "usage-pure",
  exclude: ["web.timers"]
}]
```

Notice: The "exclude" configuration which says:

> All polyfill providers accept two options: include and exclude. They are an array of strings to polyfills to be considered as not supported by the targets (include) or to be considered as supported (exclude).

This configuration has made my day and it is simply saying that do not polyfill fill for setTimeout and Map Constructor, allowing Jasmine to set the global definition and make all of the test case to run successfully. Hence Resolved my previously asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313821/why-test-case-in-jasmine-are-failing-when-comparing-two-maps) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804740/jasmine-test-case-are-failing-when-testing-settimeout-inside-function) and this one's too .

I set the exclude to:

```
"exclude": [
     "web.timers", //<--For setTimeout
     "es.map"   //For new Map()
]
```

Lastly, One thing I want is to set all of this configuration only for test scripts and  this too can be achieved with babel Env configuration BABEL_ENV that will be read by babel config file's. Just like they are using in there [master](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/babel.config.js) branch. Read [Here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#envname) and [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration)

Final babel configuration would be like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", { "modules": false }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    ["polyfill-corejs3", { "method": "usage-pure" }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
         ["polyfill-corejs3", {
           "method": "usage-pure",
           "exclude": ["web.timers"]
          }]
       ]
  }
}
```

Test Script in package.json would be:

```
"test": "BABEL_ENV=test npm run karma",
```

Hope this helps to anyone facing similar issue.