# Call retries were exceeded at ChildProcessWorker.initialize thrown while running ng test (Angular) with Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using Angular with Jest. While running ng test (nx test in my case because I am using nrwl/nx), I got this error for a component while the last test was hanging:

`Call retries were exceeded at ChildProcessWorker.initialize`

Answer (score 1):

I later found out that I had a setTimeout in my AfterViewInit() hook and this caused the error.

If you have a timer in your component, do the following in order to fix it:

- have a look on this answer: [Test a function that contains a setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772989/test-a-function-that-contains-a-settimeout)
- look on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) and on [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/testing-asynchronous-code-with-fakeasync-in-angular/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20test%20is%20running,that%20would%20occur%20within%20100ms.) article to see how to use fakeAsync() and tick() for testing async code
- if that doesn't work, wrap you test case in a setTimeout() with the same number of milliseconds as the on in the component and that should do the trick