# Unit testing a function containing setTimeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, settimeout

I have a function containing setTimeouts. I am trying to do unit testing but on the code coverage report it is always showing that the code inside the setTimeout is not executing.
Here is the code.

```
var func = function(str, type) {
  var t1 = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("ledtext").style.color = "#631313";
  }, 100);
  var t2 = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("ledtext").style.color = "#ea0707";
  }, 300);
  var t3 = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("ledtext").style.color = "#631313";
  }, 500);
  var t4 = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("ledtext").style.color = "#ea0707";
    localThisObject.startSequence(type);
  }, 700);
}
```

[image]

Code Coverage
How to do unit testing of the above code using Karma-jasmine?
Here is a list of devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-fixture": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4"
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj8f8mL2/2/)
P.S.I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine) question. It's not solving my problem.

Comment: Maybe show us how you test it?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a function which has a setTimeout with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine)

Comment: Hi @kevin I checked that question. But it is not solving my problem.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj8f8mL2/2/) @Erazihel

Comment: @Kevin No, it's not a duplicate of that once you realize how easy it is with jasmine.