# Jasmine: how to test async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

In my NodeJS app I've got the following `heplers.ts` file with one method, `wait`:

```
export const wait = async (ms: number) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
};
```

I'm currently writing a unit test to this file and this is what I have now:

```
import { setProcessEnv } from 'spec/helpers';
import { wait } from '../../util/helpers';

describe('Helper methods', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
    setProcessEnv();
  });

  it('should wait a specified amount of time', async () => {
    const TIMEOUT = 10000;
    jasmine.clock().install();  // First install the clock

    await wait(TIMEOUT);

    jasmine.clock().tick(10000); // waits till 10000 milliseconds

    expect(wait).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
    jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // uninstall clock when done
  });
  
});
```

But I'm constantly receiving

> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 20000ms (set
> by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

I've increased `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` to 20000 ms, but it still didn't work.
How such async functions could be tested?

I've found coupes examples, but they didn't work in my case: [How to test a function which has a setTimeout with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine)

**UPDATE**

This is my latest version that doesn't throw an error, but the problem is that it doesn't cover return statement lines (`return new Promise(...`):

```
it('should wait a specified amount of time', async () => {
     const TIMEOUT = 10000;

    // jasmine.clock().install();  // First install the clock
    const wait = jasmine.createSpy();

    await wait(TIMEOUT);

    // jasmine.clock().tick(1000); // waits till 10000 milliseconds
    expect(wait).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(wait).toHaveBeenCalledWith(TIMEOUT);
    
    // jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // uninstall clock when done
  });
```

Comment: your test seems to need more than 20 seconds to execute, it demands 10 secs to execute `await wait(TIMEOUT);`, another 10 sec for `jasmine.clock().tick(10000);`. What happens when you set `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 22000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by using jasmine's custom clock you need to manually call `.tick()` to move the time forward. Since you immediately await the `wait` call, the `setTimeout` within `wait` will not be reached. Thus, the promise never resolves, as you call `.tick()` after awaiting the promise.

You can fix this by not immediately awaiting the the promise returned from `wait` but instead assigning it to a variable and then moving the time ahead. Then, await the promise and check if `wait` has been called:

```
describe('Helper methods', () => {

    it('should wait a specified amount of time', async () => {
        const TIMEOUT = 10000;
        jasmine.clock().install();  // First install the clock

        const waitPromise =  wait(TIMEOUT);
        jasmine.clock().tick(10000); // waits till 10000 milliseconds

        await waitPromise; // now await the promise

        expect(wait).toHaveBeenCalled();

        jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // uninstall clock when done
    });
});
```

Note that in the above code no spy has been set up on `wait`, so `.toHaveBeenCalled` will probably fail. Check this link if you need help setting up a spy on a function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532075/3761628

---

To answer the updated question: You've incorrectly set up the spy. You need to change it to something like:

```
import { setProcessEnv } from 'spec/helpers';
import * as WaitFunction from from '../../util/helpers';
...
it('should wait a specified amount of time', async () => {
    const TIMEOUT = 10000;    
    
    const waitSpy = spyOn(WaitFunction, 'wait').and.callThrough();

    await WaitFunction.wait(TIMEOUT);

    expect(waitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(waitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(TIMEOUT);
    
  });
```

Comment: sorry eol, but it doesn't make any sense to do it like the solution that you've provided - it constantly throws an error

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense? "it constantly throws an error" - *what* is the error now?

Comment: `wait` is not a spy, after I changed it to spy, it doesn't cover the whole method :( I've updated the post

Comment: Well `wait` not being a spy is exactly what I told you in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Also you're creating the spy incorrectly.. I've updated my answer to show you how..

Comment: thank you for the updated answer, it really worked - the problem is that tests are still not covering 2 and 3 lines of the method (return Promise) statement, is Jasmine wants to check the return value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222520/discussion-between-eol-and-karen).